# WordPress boxes not showing

Tags: wordpress

I tried to enable my boxes such as custom CSS , page theme and more in my admin page. However, nothing really happened. Check the picture below.

[image: refimage]

When I checked custom CSS checkbox for example, nothing really showed up and it will be automatically unchecked once I refresh the page. I have tried to disable all plugins but the problem still exists. I'm using WordPress version 4.7.5

Comment: Any errors in console when you load the page?

Comment: i didnt get any error message